# How come my friend functions can access public stuff?

Tags: c++, overloading, friend

Below are my code. I have 3 friend functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef   MATRIX_H
#define  MATRIX_H
class Matrix
    {
    friend Matrix operator++(Matrix&);
    friend Matrix operator--(Matrix&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Matrix&);
    private:
        int dim;
        int** mat;
    public:
        Matrix(int d);
        void set(int, int, int);
        int get(int, int);
        Matrix operator+(Matrix&);
        Matrix operator-(Matrix&);
        Matrix operator*(Matrix&);
        ~Matrix();
    };

Matrix operator++(Matrix &m)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dim; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dim; j++)
            {
            int val = m.get(i,j);
            m.set(i,j,++val);
            }
        }
    return m;
    }

Matrix operator--(Matrix &m)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dim; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dim; j++)
            {
            int val = m.get(i,j);
            m.set(i,j,--val);
            }
        }
    return m;
    }

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &m)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.dim; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.dim; j++)
            {
            os << m.get(i,j) << ' ';
            }
        os<<endl;
        }
    return os;
    }

#endif
```

It's not complaining in either of them about "m.get(i,j)", which I believe is a public function...it's complaining about "m.dim", saying it's not accessible, in operator <<, but not in the first two. Why??

Comment: `std::cout << Matrix(5);` - Oops, it broke.

Comment: The title of this question appears to ask a very different question than the part at the bottom. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: This code doesn't complain about accessibility issues when I properly scope things with `std`.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn about friend functions so bear with me ok? I'm asking why is it allowing to access public members but not allowing me to access private members from those friend funtions?

Comment: It should clearly be allowing you to. What compiler are you using? -- Not that any compiler should give you a problem with something as basic as this :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to prepend `std::` before `ostream` in all locations.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Matrix&);
```

Comment: It doesn't really solve my problem... I'm having trouble with accessibility

Comment: @user1447343: [Here is a full working program](http://liveworkspace.org/code/o7wFd$6) of your code. How is your code different?

Comment: Another question...why am I allowed to use set and get in my friend function? I thought friend functions could only access non-public members?

Comment: Friend functions allow access to all public, protected and private members of a class. Perhaps your information source was wrong or you misread.